# Calling the Google API for Javascript in Ionic framework (working on web, not working on Android)

Tags: javascript, android, api, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have to log in my users with Google, so I have imported the Google API (for Javascript) in my App, like this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

The *OnLoadCallback* is like this:

```
function OnLoadCallback() {
  try {
    // set your Public API access key
    gapi.client.setApiKey(MY_API_KEY);
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function(){});
  } catch (e) {
    console.console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Then, I have a button that, upon clicking on it, triggers the function singIn():

```
var clientId = CLIENT_ID for WEB;  //web
//var clientId = CLIENT_ID for PC;  // PC
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

$scope.signIn = function() {
  var config = {
   'client_id': clientId,
   'scope': scopes,
   'immediate': false
};

gapi.auth.init(function(){
   gapi.auth.authorize(config,
    function(){
      var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
      if(!token.error){
       $state.go('app.projects');
      }
   });
 });
};
```

So I try this code. I do `ionic serve` and try to access the app from Mozilla Firefox. And it works, the prompt is prompted and I go to another state.

The problem comes when I do `ionic build android`. The APK is generated and I install it in my mobile, but the button now does NOTHING. The gapi.auth.init() callback is done, but the gapi.auth.authorize() callback is never triggered.

I have the API key in the Google's credential page, as well as a Client ID for Web Browser and the Android Client ID. I know the Android Client ID is okay because I have used a different API to contact Google and it worked on Web and on Android (though this API lacks the Google+ functionality I look, the people retrieving thing).

I am doing something wrong, that's clear, but I don't know what it is. I have double-checked the Android Client ID, also the API Key is an Android Key, and I have included the Android package name and SHA1 certificate fingerprint.

Comment: Did you set host name =http://localhost/callback  in google developer console

Comment: What? How? Do you mean domain verification?

Answer (score 0):

For android, you will need the GooglePlus and Cordova plugins for this to work.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy,
  EventEmitter,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';

import {GooglePlus} from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import {GoogleService} from '../../providers/google/google';
import {FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {User as UserProvider} from '../../providers/user/user';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {LoginPage} from '../../pages/login/login';
import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-form',
  templateUrl: 'google-form.html'
})
export class GoogleFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() success = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() error = new EventEmitter<string>();

  public platformList;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public platform: Platform,
    public loginController: LoginPage,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userProvider: UserProvider,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private googlePlus: GooglePlus,
    private googleService: GoogleService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Google Login Flow Start');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  login() {
    let platforms = this.platform.platforms();

    this.platformList = platforms.join(', ');

    if (this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
      console.log('We are mobile browser baby!');
    } else {

      console.log('Google Login Flow');
      console.log(this.loginController);

      this.googlePlus.login({
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
        'webClientId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'offline': true
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log('Google Login SUCCESS');
        console.log(res);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('Google Login FAIL');
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then install the google plus plugin for cordova.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/

The above code worked for me with a form component.